# Only three options for CPU frequencies in Ubuntu 22.04 (AMD Ryzen 3 5300u)

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, frequency

I tried installing indicator-cpufreq to set a custom frequency, but I am only getting three options(image bellow).

[options in indicator-cpufreq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRsAb.png)

Also, I tried running this in terminal:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies 

2600000 1700000 1400000 
2600000 1700000 1400000 
2600000 1700000 1400000 
2600000 1700000 1400000 
2600000 1700000 1400000 
2600000 1700000 1400000 
2600000 1700000 1400000 
2600000 1700000 1400000
```

These are the frequencies I am getting as options in indicator-cpufreq, so is it possible and safe to edit that file and add my custom frequency?

Comment: It seems turbo frequencies are disabled. Try enabling. What CPU frequency scaling driver are you using? Do `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` . I think acpi-cpufreq. If so consider trying the amd-pstate CPU frequency scaling driver. To answer your question, no do not edit the available frequencies.

Comment: You can do it with the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, but I do not know for sure if it can be done with the amd-pstate CPU frequency scaling driver.

Comment: @DougSmythies thanks for the reply, the scaling driver is set to acpi-cpufreq. Sorry to bother you but could tell me the commands to change it because I am new to Linux and I do not wand to break something. Also is turbo frequency same as boost state beacose cpupower says its active?

Comment: If turbo (or boost) was available, I would have expected to see 2600001 as an available frequency, but maybe I am out of date. For info on the amd-pstate driver see [here](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/pm/amd-pstate.html). In very recent kernels it should default to the amd-pstate driver. See [here](https://www.phoronix.com/news/AMD-P-State-How-To) if it doesn't.